# how to know ip address of packets which matched by content option in snort?

Tags: ip, snort

i am using snort-2.9.7.0 and i inspect packet by this simple code:

`alert tcp any any -> $HOME_NET any (msg:"FB found in packet content!!!"; content:"FB"; sid:10000; )`

i want to know where packet is comes from and store it. guide me.
Thanks and Regards.

Comment: when run this  command "sudo snort -A console -q -c /etc/snort/snort.conf -i wlan0" it shows the host and client address but can we show the whole packet content???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should adjust the output format of the alerts; to do that add this line in your config file:

```
output alert_fast: <full path to output file>/snort.log
```

as you [here](http://manual.snort.org/node21.html#SECTION00363000000000000000) this will print Snort alert messages with full packet headers that contains the source and destination IP addresses and will be saved in snort.log file.

**EDIT**: The log file can be in any place you like and it's name can be determined by you. for example:

```
output alert_fast: ~/Desktop/my_snort_log.txt
```

Comment: but the .log file is unreadable i want to see what snort has captured.